# NHibernate and hbm2dll update attribute

Tags: nhibernate, sdf, hbm2ddl

i'm using NHibernate with Sdf database. In my hibernate.cfg.xml file i've set:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

But this does not seem to work at all. "Update" attribute should make NHibernate generate missing tables and columns during application launch, but it does not happen.

If i want missing tables geenrated I have to set hbm2dll.auto property to "create" which is not an option for me since it drops existing db content beforehand.

I experienced the same problem with PostgreSql problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, I resolved the problem by using:

```
new SchemaUpdate(_cfg);
```

Please read about SchemaUpdate in NHibernate documentation.

You can alternatively try using Fluent NHibernate which will definetely work as you expect and even better!

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is not an alternative to SchemaUpdate

Answer (score 2):

Just got the same issue. I changed the way the property is defined. Instead of:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

I used:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Then it worked :)